# Is it possible to query for the last few hours of data using a timestamp in Redshift?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I'm trying to write a query to look for the last 2 hours of data.

I initially tried using INTERVAL:

```
select count(*) from data where created_at > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - (INTERVAL '2 hours');
```

but I get a not implemented error:

> ERROR: Not implemented
>   Detail:
>   -----------------------------------------------
>   error: Not implemented code: 1001
>   context: '!null_tst' - function: timestamp_gt_timestamptz(), funcID = 2523
>   query: 2734016
>   location: cg_expr.cpp:295
>   process: padbmaster [pid=25255]
>   -----------------------------------------------

Anyone know of a way to do this in Redshift without using absolute timestamps?

Comment: Did you try dateadd(h, -2, now)?

Comment: dateadd(hour, -12, getdate()) appears to work. Not sure how I missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  count(*)
FROM    data
WHERE   created_at >= 
dateadd(day/or_other_parameter,0,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - '2 hr'::INTERVAL
```

Using the dateadd function you can get it easily done